# How to add a horizontal line in a WordPress heading

Tags: html

I'd like to display a horizontal line in sub headings h3 which extends to the borders of the post/page content area on both sides of the heading text.

Is this possible to do with html?

Comment: this is purely a css formatting problem and not specific to WordPress - http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq; try to use the css border property.

Answer (score 0):

Two ideas :

- Simply add a `<hr/>` tag
- draw a border to the div (e.g. `<div style='border-bottom:1px solid #000;'>YOUR_CONTENTS</div>`)